# Rails 3 how to change the attempt url as parent url for ajax request using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using rails(3.0.9) and devise 1.4.8 in my app with timeout feature.
Every things works as expected in normal Http request.
If user clicks on ajax link when timeout they get redirect to /users/sign_in.js by below configuration

**initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
config.navigational_formats =  ["*/*", :html, :js]
```

In js file I reloaded the current page using location.reload(); This will redirect to login page as expected

**users/sign_in.js**

```
location.reload()
```

**Problem:**

After signed in, devise redirected to last requested url in this case ajax url But I should  redirect to the html page where the ajax request sent.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: If I'm correct your problem is your on pages `/1` and timeout occur and user click on `/2` ajax request and after login you want the user to redirect to `/1` am I correct

Comment: @Viren yes you are correct.

Comment: can you use sign.js.erb and can set the `session[:user_return_to]= referrer path` just before the location.reload() statement. FYI you need to set the js.erb

Comment: @Viren thanks for your valuable response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using Devise::FailureApp 
I have set in **lib/custom_failure.rb:**

```
require 'uri'
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp

  def redirect_url
    request.env['rack.session']["#{warden_options[:scope]}_return_to"] = URI(request.env['HTTP_REFERER']).path if request.xhr?
    super
  end
end
```